# Extract files and rename one of the file in each .rar

Tags: command-line, 7zip

Im having a bit of a struggle. I have around 1000 rar files with subfolders that i need to extract and rename in windows 10 with a batfile.
I managed to rename the file on extract but it didnt extract the rest of the content.

```
@echo off
for /r %%f in ("*.rar") do (7z e "%%f" -so -r "*.ae" > "%%f.ae")
```

also tried something like this but didnt work at all

```
for /R /F %%I IN ("*.rar") do (
 7z x -o"%%~dpI" "%%I" -aoa

 for %%f in (*.ae) do (
    ren "%%f" "%%~nI.ae"
)

)
```

So the problem is like this
10 folders with 100 rar in each folder
each rar looks pretty similar in structure like this

masterfolder

-subfolder1

1. namearchive.rar
2. -folder1 inside rar (foldername will change for each rar structure)
3. --content inside rar (image341.jpg image522.jpg image543.jpg 12.ae)

I want to extract all content with the subfolder to folder1 (foldername will change for each rar structure) and I want to rename 12.ae to the name of the .rar so its namearchive.ae (this will of course change everytime)